# How to capture video from clients computer on webpage?

Tags: php, html, flash, audio, video

What is the best way to capture live video from the users web camera through a web page? I have heard that flash is best, but (if possible) I would like to do it with HTML. I found this [site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)
 which talks about doing it with HTML5, but I don't think the browser support is that great. I would like the best browser support possible. Please tell me if you don't understand what I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? I really need your help. :-(

Comment: Do you want to publish a live stream or just show the user's webcam in your html page ?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to have something like Skype so to speak. Hope that explains it well enough. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already did live broadcasting ? It's only for desktops or mobile devices also ? ..

Comment: I want it to work with all devices, but if it isn't possible I'll make do. I am just doing some research on stack overflow to find out what the best way to do it is. What do you mean by live broadcasting?